# How does one decide on whether to use a GLMM versus an LME? And how do you select the random/fixed effects?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, random-effects-model

So I have read many textbooks and so many R tutorials that I am going crazy here. How do you decide on which model to use? I really hope this comes with experience but with the amount of modern techniques coming out and evidence for and against transformations, etc., how is anyone supposed to actually create a model that produces the correct result?

All I want to know is if there is a significant difference between the number of points in a plot covered with wood between two treatments (Low and High elephant impact). I would also like to know if any of the effects are significant. Each site has 5 plots (1,2,3,4,5). The number of points covered with wood were counted in each plot in 2013 and then again in 2014 and 2015. Therefore I have repeated measures.

My response variable is `Number` = number of points covered with wood
My fixed effects or predictor variable are `Year` (2013,2014,2015) and `Site` (High and Low)
To account for the repeated measure, `Year` and `Site` are also my random effects. Or should this actually be `Plot` (1,2,3,4,5)?

The first option is to use a GLMM, as I have both random and fixed effects; because I have count data, I selected the Poisson family:

```
model<-glmer(Number~Year*Treatment+(1|Year:Treatment),data=data,family=poisson)
```

Firstly, can `Year` and `Treatment` act as both fixed and random effects in the same model? I haven't included plot as I'm assuming the repeated measure is actually YearL is that correct?
Secondly, if my data is not normally distributed, should I log-transform it and then run the GLMM?

Or should I rather leave it untransformed and use a linear mixed effects model (LME) instead?

```
model1<-lmer(Number~Year*Treatment+(1+Year|Treatment),data=data,REML=FALSE)
```

For the LME, should I stipulate a distribution? Or does it automatically use the Gaussian distribution (Normal distribution)?
Again, can `Year` and `Treatment` be both fixed and random effects?

Could this actually be non-linear?

Comment: You have count data which means a Poisson model or one of its relatives. I would consider plot as the "subject" i.e. the grouping variable of the random effect. If you had more years I would use a crossed random effect but as it is I would treat it as a fixed effect. Thus, something like Number ~ Treatment * Year + (1 | Plot) could be appropriate based on the provided information. Random slopes could also be tested. But you should start with plotting  you data.

Comment: @Roland, thank you! So is it correct that you cannot have Treatment and Year as both fixed and random effects in the same model? So if I do what you suggest, I would run a GLMM on untransformed data with this code:
`model<-glmer(Number~Treatment*Year+(1|Plot),data=data,family=poisson)`

Comment: If you have a source which would produce correlated data or is in nature a hierarchy (say teacher within a school), then you should account for that via a LMM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have count data as the response variable then you should be using a glmm. A poisson model is appropriate so long as it is not over-dispersed or zero-inflated, in which case you will need to consider other glmms.

If I understood the description correctly then have 3 repeated measures in 2 sites where each site has 5 plots. So plots are nested within sites, but you don't have enough sites, or plots, to treat them as nested with the usual syntax `(1|site/plot)`, so instead you could use the combination of site and plot as the grouping factor `(1|site:plot)`. Treatment is clearly a fixed effect and there is no justification for treating it as random. There are only 3 years, so this can be treated as fixed too.

So I would suggest a model such as:

```
glmer(Number~Year*Treatment+(1|site:plot),data=data,family=poisson)
```

Comment: but *do* remember to check for overdispersion (e.g. [here](https://rawgit.com/bbolker/mixedmodels-misc/master/glmmFAQ.html#overdispersion))